# iOS VoiceOver accessibility - how to implement "Action X performed" after action is complete?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

For example, in the Mail app, after you delete an item via VoiceOver, you hear "Message deleted". How can I implement that for my custom action/button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `UIAccessibilityPostNotification` method.

For example in Objective-C:

`UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, @"String to be read");`

For more information see:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1615194-uiaccessibilitypostnotification